# How do I reference the same table in rails activerecord style

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do i write this query in rails active record style?

```
select distinct listmonth, 
        (select count(1) from listing where listmonth between dateadd(month, -3, l.listmonth) and dateadd(month, -1, l.listmonth)) as cnt
from listing l
group by listmonth
order by listmonth
```

Answer (score 0):

This one may suppose to be your AR style. Have a try.

```
sub_query = Listing
  .select('count(1)')
  .where('listmonth between dateadd(month, -3, l.listmonth) and dateadd(month, -1, l.listmonth)')
  .as('cnt')

Listmonth
  .select('distinct listmonth')
  .select(sub_query)
  .as('l')
  .group('listmonth')
  .order('listmonth')
```